# How to escape double quotes if the variable is coming from database?

Tags: asp-classic

I know that Double quotes can be escaped like this:

```
string test = "He said to me, ""Hello World"". How are you?"
```

or by:

```
string test = "He said to me, \"Hello World\" . How are you?"
```

But I don't want to change the value in the database, I want to get the value from database and put it into an URL. For example :

```
href="http://www.abcd.com/movie/<%= mTitle%>/"
```

If string contains double quote it breaks the URL.

Comment: Is this Classic ASP it's just VBScript doesn't support strongly typed variable declarations *(JScript does to a fashion, just not like that)*? Example `string test = "..."` would be `var test: String = "...";` in JScript and `Dim test: test = "..."` in VBScript.

Comment: @Lankymart: Looks like C# to me. Bet this is the old [asp -> aspclassic tag rewrite issue](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269402/can-we-clarify-the-asp-classic-and-asp-net-tags-for-the-uneducated).

Comment: @Paul indeed shame we can't get support for a change to the tagging logic.

Answer (score 1):

In this case you're not "escaping" the quotes, you're *URL-encoding* them.  The problem isn't the string itself.  The problem is that many "special characters" have other meanings in the context of a URL, or in some way confuse the parsing of that URL, and need to be encoded.

(In this case, it's not necessarily the URL itself, but the HTML attribute which is being confused by the quotes.)

Something like this:

```
<a href="http://www.abcd.com/movie/<%= server.urlEncode(mTitle) %>">
```

So instead of this output:

```
<a href="http://www.abcd.com/movie/A"Quoted"String">
```

You'd get this:

```
<a href="http://www.abcd.com/movie/A%22Quoted%22String">
```